# Customise Android app during installation

Tags: android, apk, google-play

Is it possible to customise an android application during installation dependant on a given code/parameter. For example, I install an app and the code/parameter is blue, then the app installs creating a blue icon in the device and using the blue theme within the application.

something like: "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redblue.core&code=blue"

If not is it possible to prompt the user during the installation for the code perhaps?

Comment: In all the applications I have seen, I do not **believe** its possible. However, I noticed many people set some of those variables on initial run.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? for example are you trying to apply different app skins for the install depending on the param? or are you trying to add/remove features based on param?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to customise an android application during installation dependant on a given code/parameter.

No.

> If not is it possible to prompt the user during the installation for the code perhaps?

No. You are welcome to ask the user for this code on the first run of your app. Note, though, that some aspects of the app (e.g., icon) are difficult to change.